# How do I allow clients to lease ip addresses with DHCP through iptables?

Tags: windows, debian, iptables, dhcp

I have looked around and I am very confused on how I can forward dhcp request to client using iptables. I understand that DHCP works on two UDP ports 67 for server side and 68 for client side. My network looks kind of like this:
[Network Topology](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ELC4i.png)

I have set INPUT, OUTPUT, FORWARD chains and flushed everything. I tried `iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 0/0 --dport 67 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -d 0/0 --sport 67 -J ACCEPT`

`iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 0/0 --dport 68 -j ACCEPT`
`iptables -A FORWARD -p udp -s 0/0 --sport 68 -j ACCEPT`

But this does not work!

iptables:

```
iptables -F

iptables -P INPUT DROP
iptables -P OUTPUT DROP
iptables -P FORWARD DROP



iptables -N accept-input



iptables -A accept-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-ALLOWED "
iptables -A accept-input -j ACCEPT



iptables -N drop-input



iptables -A drop-input -j LOG --log-prefix "INPUT-BLOCKED "
iptables -A drop-input -j DROP



iptables -N accept-output



iptables -A accept-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-ALLOWED "
iptables -A accept-output -j ACCEPT



iptables -N drop-output



iptables -A drop-output -j LOG --log-prefix "OUTPUT-BLOCKED "
iptables -A drop-output -j ACCEPT

    iptables -A INPUT -p tcp -s 0/0 --dport 22 -m state --state NEW,ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-input
iptables -A OUTPUT -p tcp -d 0/0 --sport 22 -m state --state ESTABLISHED,RELATED -j accept-output
```

I have only added this rule to see if this work and it does work!

Comment: DHCP is not a routable protocol. It operates on a single link. But you have a router between the client and the intended DHCP server. If you want this to have a chance of working, you will need to install a DHCP relay on the router, so that clients on the second subnet can reach the DHCP server on the first subnet. You also need to reconfigure the DHCP server to give out appropriate IP addresses for the second subnet, which must be different to the first subnet.

Comment: I have done all that. I have installed and configured a dhcp relay and I have configured a dhcp pool for different subnet. When I flush iptables I can get IP address, but when I  create `INPUT OUTPUT FORWARD` chains it does not work!

Comment: You never mentioned any of that and you should have! There was no way anyone could know you had done so. Anyway, you need to post the complete firewall, not just a few excerpts.

Comment: I have added firewall rules!

Comment: How about the rest of them?

Comment: I have added one more rule and I haven't added anything else yet in my firewall!

Comment: Because the DHCP relay will "forward" queries at a higher level (the application), you shouldn't use FORWARD rules at all for DHCP. You should have rules in INPUT and OUTPUT chains instead, 2x2 in total.